# MySQL error 'Key Column doesnt exist in table'

Tags: mysql

heres my input into the command line you can see I tried to add a foreign key in different ways and keep getting the same error what am I doing wrong?

```
mysql> create table membership(

-> m_no char(3) primary key,
-> m_fname varchar(15) not null,
-> m_lname varchar(15) not null,
-> m_street varchar(30) not null,
-> m_city varchar(20) not null,
-> m_st char(2) not null,
-> m_balance varchar(3));
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.06 sec)

```
mysql> create table rental(

-> r_no char(4) primary key,
-> r_date date not null,
-> foreign key (m_no) references membership(m_no));
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'm_no' doesn't exist in table

mysql> create table rental(
-> r_no char(4) primary key,
-> r_date date not null,
-> foreign key (m_no) references membership);
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'm_no' doesn't exist in table

mysql> create table rental(
-> r_no char(4) primary key,
-> r_date date not null,
-> foreign key (m_no) references membership)
-> engine=innodb;
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'm_no' doesn't exist in table


mysql> create table rental(

-> r_no char(4) primary key,
-> r_date date not null,
-> foreign key (m_no) references membership(m_no))
-> engine=innodb;
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'm_no' doesn't exist in table

mysql> create table rental(

-> r_no char(4) primary key,
-> r_date date not null);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

```
mysql> alter table rental add foreign key (m_no) references membership(m_no);

ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'm_no' doesn't exist in table
```

mysql>

Answer (score 2):

The error statement is clear. You do not have a column named 'm_no' in your rental table.

Is this what you were after:

```
Create table rental
(
    r_no char(4) primary key,
    r_date date not null,
    foreign key (r_no) references membership(m_no)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as the error message states: `rental` doesn't have a column named `m_no`.

Either reference an existing column (i.e. `FOREIGN KEY (r_no) REFERENCES membership(m_no)`), or add an `m_no` column to `rental`. I am not sure which you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very new to MySQL and didn't realize you had to create the column before making it a foreign key. I thought declaring the foreign key created the column.

Comment: Nope, declaring the foreign key only creates the constraint. You have to add the column yourself.

Comment: i have a new issue now,

`mysql> create table price(
    -> p_code char(1) not null,
    -> p_description varchar(20),
    -> p_rentfee decimal(2,2) not null,
    -> p_dylatefee decimal(2,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql> create table movie(
    -> mv_no char(4) not null,
    -> mv_name varchar(50) not null,
    -> mv_year char(4) not null,
    -> mv_cost decimal(2,2) not null,
    -> mv_genre varchar(15) not null,
    -> p_code char(1) not null,
    -> foreign key (p_code) references price(p_code));
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
mysql>`

Comment: i also cant figure out how to format the comment on here, im having a bad day

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the foreign key reference to the `r_no` column in the `rental` table:

```
create table rental(
 r_no char(4) primary key,
 r_date date not null,
 foreign key (r_no) references membership(m_no));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be5c)